# Equivalent of .text property for UISegmentedControl?

Tags: xcode, email, properties, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a MFMailViewController that shows what the user answered on the previous page. There were also some areas which they had to pick Yes or No through a segmentedcontrol object.

What I mean here is the property for the TextField is Name.text, but what is the .text for UISegmentedControl?

For example, if the user picked "Yes" in the SegmentedControl, it would show 'Do you agree to these terms = YES' in the Mail composer.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `titleForSegmentAtIndex:` method.

You could do something like this.

```
NSString *selectedSegmentText = [yourSegmentedControl titleForSegmentAtIndex:yourSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex];
myUILabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Do you agree to these terms = %@", selectedSegmentText];
```

Let's say the user picked the "Yes" segment. Then the output of this code would be: "Do you agree to these terms = Yes";

Hope this helps!